# Is 2 ranks in V.A.N.S. better than 2 ranks in Perception Training?

Tags: fallout-4

Let's say I wanted +2 Perception.

I could...

1. Put two points into Perception.
2. Put two points into [VANS](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/VANS); the second rank gives you +2 Perception.

Seems like for 2 points I could have +2 Perception, or I could have +2 Perception and bonus VANS pathfinding.

VANS pathfinding isn't the best perk, but is there any downside to taking 2 ranks of VANS instead of 2 ranks of Perception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that VANS gives a +2 bonus to Perception. It does not give +2 Perception.

This means that rank 2 VANS will not unlock Perception perks.

Comment: And when you go into vats there's a silly green arrow. Nope.